# Laravel migrations, specifying table to insert data

Tags: laravel

how do u specify which table to use in laravel? all my data is being added to users table yet I have admins table where I want to submit data.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Show up some code also.

Comment: Thanks @Imran, have two tables, I need to insert both admin users and normal users, when I click submit to add data to admins table it gives me this error  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'first_name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users`... so I see it submited to users table instead of admins table... how do I specify... am new to laravel though...

Comment: Answer added. Best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel each table represent a `Model`. By default if your table name is `users` then your model name should be `User`. I mean if you use `User` model by default Laravel will think you have am table named as `users`. If you want to change that table name, for example if you have a table named as `user` and your model name is also `User` than you have to specify your table name in your `User` model class like this

`protected $table = 'user'`

So, if you want to insert something in your `user` table now then you can do it by using your `User` model. If you have another model named as for example `posts`, then you should have another model named as `Post`. So, now you can use your Post model to insert/updated or any other related task using your `Post` model.

So, shortly, in Laravel you need different models to work with different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get some insight, when saving an admin record in the `store` method, is the record an instance of the `Admin` class? How I would approach scenarios where I have admin users is have an extra column in the `users` table called `is_admin` which is a boolean. The default value should be set to false when creating a new user. Else when you change the value to true, the user becomes an admin. That way, you won't be dealing with two different tables, just one `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

you create a migration e.g

```
add_user_id_to_posts_table
```

by writing

```
php artisan make:migration add_user_id_to_posts_table
```

then in your database/migrations folder you get a new file with a date of creation and the name you gave.

in this file you'll find 2 method up() and down()

in up() methods you'll have

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    });
}
```

where the 'posts' is the name of your table

Comment: Thanks @FiliusBonacci, Maybe I did not explain cleary am sorry, I have migrated two tables one is users table the other is admins table, I have no problem inserting in users but while adding admin users in admin table the data is redirected to users table, how do I make it go to admins table? I get this error when I submit SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'first_name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `first_name`, `second_name`, `position`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , ,